WCF ServiceBehavior LifeCycle
I am curious as to what the lifeycle / lifetime is of a WCF ServiceBehavior is in .NET 4.6.1. Is the ServiceBehavior class instantiated during the first creation of a service or instantiated every call to a given endpoint in WCF. Any help or link to documentation would be a appreciated, I have had a hard time pinning it down.
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="**<<removed>>.ServiceBehavior**">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="300" maxConcurrentSessions="300" maxConcurrentInstances="300" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceCredentials>
       
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>


Referring to this document, I think it was helpful to you.

Since the InstanceContextMode is not specified in that config then the default value of PerSession would be used. If the channel allows a session to remain active, then you will 1..300 instances at any given point depending on the number of active sessions. If sessions are not allowed then you will have more of a PerCall lifetime.
See InstanceContextMode Enum.

Gotcha that makes sense, so the Attribute defined on the service itself will also dictate the lifetime of the service behavior?

Yes, this setting is not accessible via the ServiceBehavior config, not sure why, but it is part of the overall behavior of the service.

Also, you might find the ConcurrencyMode applicable here. ConcurrencyMode can be used in conjunction with InstanceContextMode. Both are not available in the behavior config, for whatever reasons.
